# change div colour with js if else conditiond

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hope someone can help with this.  I'm trying to change the background colour of a "div id" using an if else statement.  So that if "udata" is greater than 70 the background of the box containing the result will turn green, or based on the other if conditions other colours.  Once I can get this to work the "udata" value will be supplied by a php pull from a database.

I've search the existing links but I haven't found this combination of colour change, div background and if else statements.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BoxTEST.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function () { 

        var udata = [53];

        if (udata >= 70) {
        document.getElementById("centerbox1").style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
        }
        else  
        if (udata >= 51 && udata.value <70)  
        {
        document.getElementById("centerbox1").style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
        }  
        else  
        if (udata <=50)  
        {
        document.getElementById("centerbox1").style.backgroundColor = '#FF6C60';
        }
     }
 </script>
 </head>
  <body>
    <div class="containerbox">
        <div id="centerbox1" style= min-width:25%; max-height: 90px">
          <div class="value">
          <p><span style="color: #fff ;font-weight:bold; font-size:36px">53%</span>
          <br>
          <span style="color: #fff ; font-weight:bold">Utilisation</span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: And what is wrong with your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

removed udata.value and made it udata and invoked your function.
use the script before the end of the body.

find the working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdkzzj91/2/)

```
<div class="containerbox">
  <div id="centerbox1" style= min-width:25%; max-height: 90px">
    <div class="value">
    <p><span style="color: #fff ;font-weight:bold; font-size:36px">53%</span>
    <br>
    <span style="color: #fff ; font-weight:bold">Utilisation</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  (function () { 
    var udata = [53];
    if (udata >= 70) {
      document.getElementById("centerbox1").style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
    }
    else if (udata >= 51 && udata < 70)
    {
      document.getElementById("centerbox1").style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
    }  
    else if (udata <=50)  
    {
      document.getElementById("centerbox1").style.backgroundColor = '#FF6C60';
    }
  })();    
</script>
```

Comment: This worked well now onto making the text "53%" work from the PHP database pull.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a *function literal* by wrapping your JavaScript code in a `function() { }` block. This means it's not being executed.

Even if you remove that code from the `function() { }` block, it's not going to work for several reasons:

1. Since the `<script>` element comes before the rest of the HTML, it's being parsed and executed before the `<div id="centerbox1">` element is loaded, meaning `document.getElementById("centerbox1")` won't work. The `<script>` tag needs to be placed *after* the HTML it's supposed to affect.
2. When you declare `var udata = [53]`, you're not setting it to a number. Enclosing a value in brackets (`[]`) means you're creating an array. That array contains one element, which is the number 53. If you want to declare `udata` as just the number by itself, use `var udata = 53`.
3. In your first `else if` condition, you suddenly use `udata.value`. The variable `udata` doesn't have a `value` property; you should just use `udata` by itself, i.e.:

   ```
   else if (udata >= 51 && udata < 70)
   ```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyogbj4f/) with the proposed corrections. I changed some of the inline CSS (i.e. removed `color: #fff` to make text visible).

Comment: thank you for the explanation, really helps someone when they are starting off.  Some stupid errors in my code I think from trying to many things. Cheers Rob

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and tried to run it. It failed only due to typos, missing quotes, etc.
So I made it a bit tidier and viola, seems to work:

HTML:

```
<body onload="zzz()">
<div class="containerbox">
    <div id="centerbox1" style="min-width:25%; max-height:90px">
        <div class="value">
            <p>
                <span style="color: #000000 ;font-weight:bold; font-size:36px">53%</span>
                <br>
                <span style="color:#000000; font-weight:bold">Utilisation</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
zzz = function() { 
    var udata = 49;
    var element = document.getElementById("centerbox1");
    if (udata >= 70)
        element.style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
    else if (udata >= 51 && udata.value <70)  
        element.style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347'; 
    else if (udata <=50)  
        element.style.backgroundColor = '#FF6C60';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try loading your script *after* the  tag. It's being executed before the DOM loads, most likely.

Or, by referencing the function through a variable, instead of letting the script self-execute, your script will automatically be executed only after the DOM is available.

http://jsfiddle.net/5pfhgk5c/

```
var colorBox = function () {

    var udata = [100];

    if (udata >= 70) {
        document.getElementById("centerbox1").style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
    } else if (udata >= 51 && udata.value < 70) {
        document.getElementById("centerbox1").style.backgroundColor = '#F8D347';
    } else if (udata <= 50) {
        document.getElementById("centerbox1").style.backgroundColor = '#FF6C60';
    }
}
colorBox(); // Call the script like this
```